# Sending a spreadsheet through email

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am trying to send an email from Excel which shows a timetable as shown.

[image: shown]

On Friday I was able to send the email but now it doesn't seem to be working.

I would like to send the range in colour if possible as well.

```
Private Sub SendEmail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ("xxxx@hotmail.com")
    .Subject = "Test Mail"
    .Body = "This is a test email." & Time   ' Time refers to a range of cells e.g. a1:h15
    .Display
    .Send
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing `On Error Resume Next` and rerunning.  That statement suppresses errors messages, which can make debugging very tricky.  When you rerun the code will still fail, but this time it will tell you why.  If you don't know how to fix the error, add it to the question.

Comment: `.To = ("xxxx@hotmail.com")` should be `.To = "xxxx@hotmail.com"` Remove `Set OlObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")` and `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this. This is something I wrote from a previous program and is the same style in which you are going about this. Be weary that if you use `.Send`, you will need to "OK" the pop-up from Outlook.

```
'-------Send Mail----------
    strbody = "TEST:" & strbody 'Build header.
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@something.com" 'Email to be sent to here.
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test! " & Format(Date, "mmm-dd-yy")
        .Body = strbody
        .attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display 'Can use .Send however it will ask for verification within outlook
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: When i tried this solution i had to connect to some docs.live where i had no password for. Any idea what this is

Comment: I've never had that come up? Off of what I looked up it could be a sharepoint issue as it connects to outlook aswell, or possible sheet protection could be effecting the .attachments?